# Does Scanf function ignore the Enter key when looking for %d match?

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm new to to C language and I'm studying it on a book by Kim N. King. It say that the `scanf()` looks for number pattern ignoring the whitespaces but I think it also skips on Enter key. While if it looks for characters it obviously takes the whitespace also.

Therefore in this example code I have to use `getchar()` to clear the stream before the second `scanf()`, otherwise the second one would be executed without waiting for user's input.

```
printf("Enter a char: ");
scanf("%c", &ch1);
getchar();
printf("\nEnter another char: ");
scanf("%c", &ch2);
```

If I look for digits instead, I have no problems.

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("\nEnter another number: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
```

Is my assumption (It skips the Enter key) right?

Comment: What is "Enter keyword"? A newline character is one of whitespaces.

Comment: Whitespaces are not necessarily single spaces. `isspace` searches for whitespaces, which are newlines, carriage returns, line feeds, vertical/horizontal tabs, and single spaces (maybe I forgot some).

Comment: sorry i mean enter key, or return key. I edit it.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. There will be no "key" to be read from C stream, so it will never be skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key inputs a `newline` (`\n`), which is a whitespace character.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, *fscanf()*

> A directive that is a conversion specification defines a set of matching input sequences, as
>   described below for each specifier. A conversion specification is executed in the following steps:
>
> 8. Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>      the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier. [....]

So, **yes**, any leading whitespace (*present in the input buffer*) is (are) *skipped* or ignored for `%d`.